# Help for a family motto: "Upon the windy hill"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I just need a Latin translation of:

"Upon the windy hill" or "At home on the windy hill"

It's a reference to the family home from the 1800's, and I have tried using several translators. They don't work for Latin, and I know nothing of the declinations and cases. I don't want to say the wrong thing.

Comment: I think mottos usually hint at some principle or founding family events rather than just describe an object.  If you are talking about the origin of your family, couldn't you say at least something like "From the windy hill" or "United by the windy hill"?  If you like something like that, be clear about what noun should be understood in connection with the hill (e.g., "people united" or "family united,") since that would change the Latin.   I am thinking about something like "De colle ventorum familia unita" (From the hill of winds, a united family), but others might have better suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Vegawatcher. I am in the middle of designing a coat of arms. Trying to do as much research as possible to get it right.

Answer (score 1):

Salve,

Here are a few things I came up with:

A literal translation:

> *Domi in colle ventōsō* -- At home on a windy hill/a hill full of wind.

These three make use of the ablative of source, which indicates the ancestry of a person or object:

> *ē* or *ex colle ventōsō* -- Out of/from a windy hill

> *a* or *ab* colle ventōsō* -- Out of/from a windy hill

> *colle ventōsō* -- Out of/from a windy hill

I might recomend *colle ventōsō* as it is the shortest.

Hope this helps.